# Click an onclick with invoke-webrequest via PowerShell

Tags: javascript, powershell

Using the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet in a PowerShell script to send an HTTPS requests to a web page - how can you send a dynamic click which expands the page with search fields?  This is  on the HTML doc that contains value="Yes" onclick="showSearch().  This is a javascript event handler I believe - so how would you do this if you need to address the search fields that are  exposed by this click action?  I need to then populate eight $form.Fields to get a return.

Comment: Please see under https://stackoverflow.com/help about providing an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example). Questions without code generally go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` can only make HTTP requests and return the result. You would need a JavaScript interpreter to execute the javascript locally. Your problem might be better solved by using a browser automation API like Selenium